# Hide dropdown on form submit

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

**I'm using the [Typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) directive included in [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io)**

So, what happens to me often (specially on slower connections) I type something in my search input box... (typeahead triggered).. then I press enter or hit submit... and the form submits... but typeahead's dropdown shows anyways! Very annoying since I hide the search form after submitting the form, and the dropdown just floats there...

worth mentioning that this happens when appending dropdown to the body

```
<form ng-submit="Ctrl.onSubmit()">
    <input
        id="fld-page-search"
        class="form-control input-lg"
        type="search"
        data-ng-model="Ctrl.searchTerm"
        placeholder="Search by ...."
        required
        data-ng-minlength="2"
        data-typeahead="item.name for item in Ctrl.typeahead($viewValue)"
        data-typeahead-min-length="2"
        data-typeahead-append-to-body="true"
        data-typeahead-on-select="Ctrl.openFund($item)"
        data-typeahead-focus-first="false"
        data-typeahead-template-url="/static/tpl/fund-discovery-typeahead.html"
    >
```

I would like to have an option to hide the typeahead's dropdown (and cancel all the request queue) in my onSubmit method

I tried doing

```
var $typeaheadList = $('#' + $searchInput.attr('aria-owns'));
$typeaheadList.hide();
```

which did the trick, but when I opened/expanded the search box again and trying to use the search input typeahead again, the list stayed hidden

Comment: You're mixing up AngularJS and jQuery which is, the way you seem to be doing it, basically a recipe for disaster.

Comment: That's why I said it, it's ugly and I don't like it. I want the proper, angular way.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen: I am doing
var form = $scope.pageSearchForm;
form.$setSubmitted();

in my controller, but the typeahead is not getting that at all and still executing the queue it has... and displaying the popup even if I processed and submitted the form.

Answer (score 0):

I found an ugly solution to it that it seems to be working, but I certainly don't like it.

```
$typeaheadList.hide();
$searchInput.one('keyup', function(){
    $typeaheadList.show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found ugly work solution without pure Jquery. 
So when I need to close tupeahead, you can simply loose focus from typeahead input, and then return it back. I Use this code:

```
               //this is close for typeahead control
                $timeout(function () {
                    angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.glyphicon-refresh')).click();
                });
                //here is server call, or other action
                $timeout(function () {
                    angular.element(element[0].querySelector('input[type=text]')).select();
                });
```

This code I put to my cusom directive that wraps angular-ui-typeahead. Hope this will help.